# Oracle join a table using a variable field

Tags: sql, oracle, join

I'm trying to get the rent rate for which a cage is to be charged with for each month. Here's the logic behind how to get it:

1. If the rate is defined in the `cage` table use that table's foreign key to link to the `rate` table.
2. If the rate is defined in the `rack` table use that table's foreign key to link to the `rate` table.
3. If the rate is defined in the `room` table use that table's foreign key to link to the `rate` table.
4. If all of the above is `false` return `$0.00` (*free rent*).

So here are the tables for you to visually understand what I currently have.

#### Cages

```
id    cage_number     rate_id     rack_id    room_id
----------------------------------------------------
1     FG-12           600         1          1
2     FG-13           600         1          1
3     FG-14           NULL        2          1
4     FG-15           NULL        2          3
```

#### Racks

```
id    rack_number     rate_id
-----------------------------
1     BN-806          700
2     BN-971          NULL
```

#### Rooms

```
id    room_number     rate_id
-----------------------------
1     UM-100          800
2     UM-150          900
3     UM-200          NULL
```

#### Rates

```
id   rate_id    effective_on    rate_value
------------------------------------------
1    600        01-Apr-2015     0.67
2    600        01-Oct-2016     0.80
3    700        01-Jan-2016     0.56
4    800        01-Jul-2012     0.61
5    800        01-Dec-2015     0.85
6    900        01-Feb-2015     0.75
7    900        01-Mar-2015     0.79
8    900        01-Apr-2015     0.90
```

So as you can see there are multiple rows for each `rate_id` because the price changes from time to time. I already have a query to get the correct rate for each `rate_id` by checking the `effective_on` field:

```
SELECT *
FROM rates r
WHERE r.id = (
  SELECT MAX(rr.id) AS curr
  FROM rates rr
  WHERE rr.rent_id = r.rent_id
    AND TRUNC(rr.effective_on) <= TRUNC(sysdate)
)
```

Let's go back to what my main problem is. I need to join the `rate` table using the `rate_id` located on 3 different tables.

#### Current Solution

My current approach is to join the `rate` table 3 times using 3 different aliases but since there could be multiple rows for the rate, all 3 instances could have multiple rows each which results in a lot of un-needed rows.

```
FROM cages c
  LEFT JOIN racks rk ON rk.id = c.rack_id
  LEFT JOIN rooms rm ON rm.id = c.room_id
  LEFT JOIN rates cr ON cr.rate_id = c.rate_id
  LEFT JOIN rates rkr ON rkr.rate_id = rk.rate_id
  LEFT JOIN rates rmr ON rmr.rate_id = rm.rate_id
```

#### Attempted (but miserably failed)

I was thinking of a solution where I would only need to join the `rate` table once to fix that problem but when I tried it - it failed (as expected).

```
FROM cages c
  LEFT JOIN racks rk ON rk.id = c.rack_id
  LEFT JOIN rooms rm ON rm.id = c.room_id
  CASE
    WHEN c.rate_id IS NOT NULL
      THEN LEFT JOIN rates r ON r.rate_id = c.rate_id
    WHEN rk.rate_id IS NOT NULL
      THEN LEFT JOIN rates r ON r.rate_id = rk.rate_id
    WHEN rm.rate_id IS NOT NULL
      THEN LEFT JOIN rates r ON r.rate_id = rm.rate_id
  END
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't use a case expression to decide *which* join condition to use, but you can use a case expression on the right-hand side of the condition, to decide what you're trying to match the rates table's ID against:

```
FROM cages c
  LEFT JOIN racks rk ON rk.id = c.rack_id
  LEFT JOIN rooms rm ON rm.id = c.room_id
  LEFT JOIN rates r ON r.rate_id =
  CASE
    WHEN c.rate_id IS NOT NULL THEN c.rate_id
    WHEN rk.rate_id IS NOT NULL THEN rk.rate_id
    WHEN rm.rate_id IS NOT NULL THEN rm.rate_id
  END
```

But it's simpler to use [`coalesce()`](http://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/functions033.htm#SQLRF00617) for the outer join condition on the rates table:

```
  LEFT JOIN rates r ON r.rate_id = COALESCE(c.rate_id, rk.rate_id, rm.rate_id)
```

Or more usefully on a subquery against the rates table that finds the most recent rate for each ID:

```
select cages.cage_number,
  rates.rate_id as rate_id,
  nvl(rates.rate_value, 0)
from cages
left join racks on racks.id = cages.rack_id
left join rooms on rooms.id = cages.room_id
left join (
  select rate_id,
    max(rate_value) keep (dense_rank last order by effective_on) as rate_value
  from rates
  where effective_on <= trunc(sysdate)
  group by rate_id
) rates on rates.rate_id = coalesce(cages.rate_id, racks.rate_id, rooms.rate_id);

CAGE_    RATE_ID COALESCE(RATES.RATE_VALUE,0)
----- ---------- ----------------------------
FG-13        600                           .8
FG-12        600                           .8
FG-14        800                          .85
FG-15                                       0
```

The subquery ignores rates that start in the future, as you were already doing; and uses [`keep dense_rank last` to avoid the self-join](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/functions095.htm#SQLRF00653).

That subquery is then used as an inline view (aliased back to 'rates' for simplicity). The join condition uses coalesce to join on the cage's rate ID if it's set; then the rack ID; then the room ID. Finally there's another coalesce to set the final selected value to zero if there was no match at all.

---

As @mathguy pointed out, this may end up doing unnecessary work - if the cage has a rate ID there's no point looking at the other tables for that cage. Depending on how selective the data is that may not matter too much, but if it does affect performance you could consider modifying the outer join conditions to eliminate some of them:

```
from cages
left join racks on racks.id = cages.rack_id
  and cages.rate_id is null
left join rooms on rooms.id = cages.room_id
  and cages.rate_id is null
  and racks.rate_id is null
left join (
  ...
```

Comment: Thank you so much! I didn't know about `COALESCE`. Such a nice feature. I did use your second solution to make it simpler although I've gotten plenty of answers (from my other questions) that uses `keep` and `dense_rank` but I've never really understood what those do even when reading the official docs.

Comment: Assuming a "relatively large fraction" of rows in the `cages` table have non-null `rate_id`, it may be more efficient to join only the remaining rows to the other two tables to find a `rate_id` (then use `union all` to put everything together) - right? I'm asking just to make sure I am not missing something. I just posted what I mean in a different Answer, as it wouldn't fit in a Comment.

Comment: @mathguy - maybe; would need to test with real data. Also depends on how selective the room, rack and rate IDs are perhaps. You could also modify the outer join conditions, e.g. `left join racks on racks.id = cages.rack_id and cages.rate_id is null` ?

Answer (score 1):

Here's a different way to get the proper `rate_id` for each cage. Depending on how many `null`s you have in the different tables, it may be more efficient (faster) than doing the left joins on the entire tables. The idea is to collect the `rate_id` from the `cages` table when it is not null, and only when it is null to join to the racks table, and only when that doesn't work either, to join only the remaining rows to the rooms table.

I am not showing how to "connect" this to the `rates` table - either approach in Alex's answer will do. (I would use the second version, again for efficiency.)

```
with
     prep ( id, cage_number, rate_id, room_id ) as (
       select c.id, c.cage_number, rk.rate_id, c.room_id
       from cages c left outer join racks rk on c.rack_id = rk.id
       where c.rate_id is null
     )
select  id, cage_number, rate_id
  from  cages
  where rate_id is not null
union all
select  id, cage_number, rate_id
  from  prep
  where rate_id is not null
union all
select  p.id, p.cage_number, rm.rate_id
  from  prep p left outer join rooms rm on p.room_id = rm.id
  where p.rate_id is null
;
```